# Specify docker network scope in the compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

What do I put into my compose file used by the `docker stack deploy` command to replicate the creation of a network using the command `docker network create test --scope swarm`? So I need to change the scope to swarm for the bridge driver. I've been googling a log but can't find anything.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specifying-custom-networks

Comment: @Sergiu I tried the `driver_opts` prop but no effect

Comment: https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/420

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well my solution was just to use the `overlay` driver, it's swarm-scoped by default